# HTML5 input of type "email" passing invalid email format

Tags: html

I have an `input` field of type `email`. When I put `m@m.c`, it seem to be ok with the format. However, checking the same at https://verifalia.com/validate-email gives error `Invalid email format: the domain part of the email address does not comply with IETF standards.`

I am using `validator` library's `isEmail` function which also seem to agree with `verifalia`. Which one is correct? Is it safe to use `type=email` in a `form`?

Comment: There is always a tradeoff. The more accurate you want the more time/complexity you add. Each of them are correct to what accuracy it claims.  If you refer, its just checking standard format `username@hostname.tld` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Constraint_validation

Comment: Is `m.c` a valid domain? No it's not.

Comment: Be careful with email address validation. The last thing you want to do is reject a real person's working email address. The only way to _really_ validate if an email address is good is to send mail to the address, and if you're doing that then it's OK, in my opinion, to allow things like `m@m.c` to slip through the first line of validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is referring to the fact that a valid [domain name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_domain_name) must consist of 3 to 63 alphanumeric characters (including hyphens) within the hostname and 2 to 63 letters (including hyphens) for the top level domain name (3 to 4 letters being the norm). `host-is-3-to-63-letters-digits-hyphens.tld-is-2-to-63-letters-hyphens` and `a-1.de` are valid, but `m.c` is not.

For simple client-side validation, use [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute and this regex as it's value:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{3,63}\.[a-zA-Z\-]{2,63}
```

Of course the regex above isn't foolproof, since it validates if there are any hyphens at the beginning or end of a name or if the hostname has any consecutive hyphens, or if there is a sub-domain, etc. (see [Domain Naming Conventions](https://registry.gov.in/domiannamingcon.php#:%7E:text=Domain%20Naming%20Conventions,-Following%20are%20the&text=Domains%20can%20contain%20the%20English,both%20third%20and%20fourth%20positions.)).

The example below is a `<form>` that submits data to a live test server. If the data entered is invalid, the `required` attribute stops the form from submitting and a pop-up error message appears. If the data is valid , then the form submits it to the server and the iframe below will display the response (look for `user-email:` to verify data in the response).

```css
:root {
  font: 1.75ch/1.15 "Segoe UI";
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: fit-content;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

input {
  height: 1.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font: inherit
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 99%
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="http://httpbin.org/post" target="response">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Registration</legend>
    
    <label for="user-email">Email Address: </label><input id="user-email" name="data-email" type="email" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{3,63}\.[a-zA-Z\-]{2,63}" required>
    
    <input class="btn" type="submit">

    <iframe name="response"></iframe>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `3 to 4 letters being the norm` — except for the >300 two-letter country-code top level domains. My email is at a `.us` domain. Many email "validators" used to reject my actual email address because the domain wasn't exactly 3 letters. People have, thankfully, learned better since then.

Comment: Be careful coming up with your own pattern for an email address. I tried this snippet and it rejected `sd+pete@foobar.us` saying "Please match the requested format". That is a perfectly valid address and should be allowed.

Comment: @StephenP as I stated in my answer, "Of course the regex above isn't foolproof, since it validates if there are any hyphens at the beginning or end of a name or if the hostname has any consecutive hyphens, or if there is a sub-domain, etc. (see [Domain Naming Conventions](https://registry.gov.in/domiannamingcon.php#:%7E:text=Domain%20Naming%20Conventions,-Following%20are%20the&text=Domains%20can%20contain%20the%20English,both%20third%20and%20fourth%20positions.))."